# Condition error in SPARQL query from OWL file

Tags: sparql, owl, semantic-web

in a sparql query, I want to list people who are older than 35 years. but I get the following error. what would be the reason?

(The result doesn't change even if I do **`?yas > 35`**. I still get the error.)

**QUERY:**

```
PREFIX uni:<http://muratkilinc.com/~ontologies/izmir.owl#>
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX un: <http://www.w3.org/2007/ont/unit#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT ?adi ?soyadi ?yas
WHERE
{
    ?turistler uni:yas ?yas > "35" .
    ?turistler uni:yas ?yas.
    ?turistler uni:adi ?adi.
    ?turistler uni:soyadi ?soyadi.      
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
Error 400: Parse error: 
Encountered " ">" "> "" at line 9, column 33.
Was expecting one of:
    "values" ...
    "graph" ...
    "optional" ...
    "minus" ...
    "bind" ...
    "service" ...
    "let" ...
    "exists" ...
    "not" ...
    "filter" ...
    "{" ...
    "}" ...
    ";" ...
    "," ...
    "." ...
```

Comment: so what is `?turistler uni:yas ?yas > "35" .` for a syntax? Did you check the SPARQL W3C docs? It should be something like `?turistler uni:yas ?yas . FILTER(?yas > 35)` or `FILTER(?yas > "35"^^xsd:int)` (we don't know the dataype of the `?yas` bindings ...

Comment: Thank you. I will examine the SPARQL W3C docs carefully. When I tried with the FILTER(?yas > 35), the query worked. @AKSW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put these kinds of boolean conditions in a SPARQL query, you have to use a `FILTER` constraint. Like so:

```
PREFIX uni:<http://muratkilinc.com/~ontologies/izmir.owl#>
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX un: <http://www.w3.org/2007/ont/unit#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT ?adi ?soyadi ?yas
WHERE
{
    ?turistler uni:yas .
    ?turistler uni:yas ?yas.
    ?turistler uni:adi ?adi.
    ?turistler uni:soyadi ?soyadi.
    FILTER(?yas > 35)      
}
```

The [SPARQL W3C doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query) is a great resource to read up on what kinds of [filter expression](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#expressions) you can use, and how to work with different value datatypes (strings, ints, dates, etc.).